# how to use match cellphone number format in jquery?

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, phone-number

my question is cellphone number format match issue.

I want check format '010-1234-5678' or '010-123-4567' is correct format.

I used jquery validator.js. but I don`t know 'Regular Expression'.

help me please.

Comment: A good place to start learning [regex in javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Var Pattern =/\d{3}-\d{3,4}-\d{4}/